# How to calculate skewness for a mesh?

Tags: finite-volume, mesh, openfoam, unstructured-mesh

I am writing a code to calculate mesh quality stats such as: cell volume, face areas and non-orthogonality between faces (basically something like OpenFOAM's `checkMesh`).

As per [F. Moukalled et al](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319168739), a mesh is skewed when the line connecting adjacent cells centroids does not pass through the centroid of the straddling face connecting the two cells. For example, if face centroid is denoted by $f$ and $f'$ is the intersection between the line connecting the two cells and the face, $f$ and $f'$ coincides for non-skewed meshes.

So, what is the metric to measure skewness?

I found the following code used in OpenFOAM to calculate skewness, but the math behind it is not very clear:

Note: the `/* */` comments are mine, however, I am not 100% sure about my interpretation of the variables.

```
/* fCtrs[facei] is the face centroid of the current straddling face */
/* ownCc is the centroid of the cell that owns facei */
/* neiCc is the centroid of the neighbor cell */

vector Cpf = fCtrs[facei] - ownCc;
vector d = neiCc - ownCc;

// Skewness vector
/* the & operator is an overloaded operator that represents dot product */
/* ROOTVSMALL is a constant, equals "1.0e-18" (defined somewhere else), that prevent errors when dividing by zero */
/* fAreas[facei] returns the area normal vector of the straddling face */
vector sv =
    Cpf
    - ((fAreas[facei] & Cpf)/((fAreas[facei] & d) + ROOTVSMALL))*d;

vector svHat = sv/(mag(sv) + ROOTVSMALL);
```

Comment: You can have mesh skewed (non-orthogonal) but the line connecting centers of adjacent cells would pass through the center of the face between those cells. Just imagine each cell is a rhombus of the same dimensions.

Comment: @MaximUmansky But aren't skewness and non-orthogonality two different things? If the line connecting centers of adjacent cells passes through the center of the face, the mesh is non-skewed but may be non-orthogonal (depending on the angle between face normal vector and the line joining the cells centroids).

Comment: I thought skewness is the same as non-orthogonality. If you google "skewed grid" it would show images that to me look like non-orthogonal grids. But what is your definition of grid skewness?

Comment: @MaximUmansky Well, this is actually my question. The book I referenced describes skewness as the line connecting the cells centers not passing through the face center, but no metric or whatsoever.

Comment: There are some metrics of skewness on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_mesh#Skewness. I don't know what those are based on, if there are real references; but at least a starting point.

Comment: Do you know what ownCc and so on are? It is not very descriptive as is. I think I am familiar with the skewness definition you give but I can't figure out the math without knowing what the variables stand for.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I did my best to explain the code, please check the edits. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussions and the paper, OpenFOAM seems to have implemented a measure of skewness. This answer is not an explanation why the different definitions of skewness might be equivalent, I am just going to justify why this is a measure of skewness. Consider following two elements -for sake of simplicity-

[image]

Blue arrow is the outward surface normal `fAreas[facei]`, red dots are, from left to right, `ownCc`, `fCtrs[facei]` and `neiCc`. Now, `Cpf` is the vector pointing from `ownCc` to `fCtrs[facei]` and `d` is the vector pointing from `fCtrs[facei]` to `neiCc`.

This is where I remind that, given two compatible vectors $v,w$: $$v\cdot w = \|v\| \ \|w\| \ cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $w$.

Let's get back to the formula `((fAreas[facei] & Cpf)/((fAreas[facei] & d) + ROOTVSMALL))`. `(fAreas[facei] & Cpf)` will just give us the norm of `fAreas[facei]` times `Cpf` as those two vectors point in the same direction (in this example, if `Own` was a trapezoid it would not be) thus $\theta=0$. `(fAreas[facei] & d)` may give us a variety of different positive values, but the important points is if `fAreas[facei]` and `d` point in the same direction, hence no skewness, it will be the norm of `fAreas[facei]` times `d`, e.g. `[norm(fAreas[facei])*norm(Cpf)]/[norm(fAreas[facei])*norm(d)] = norm(Cpf)/norm(d)`. This simplifies

```
sv = Cpf - ((fAreas[facei] & Cpf)/((fAreas[facei] & d) + ROOTVSMALL))*d;
```

into

```
sv = Cpf - norm(Cpf)*d/norm(d); // Note that d/norm(d) is a unit vector pointing
                                // in the same direction as Cpf.
```

into

```
sv = Cpf - Cpf; // e.g. zero vector
```

Hence, if the mesh is not skewed, `sv` -and as a result `svHat`- will be zero. If it is skewed, as in the picture, the math is slightly different

```
sv = Cpf - ((fAreas[facei] & Cpf)/((fAreas[facei] & d) + ROOTVSMALL))*d;
```

becomes

```
sv = 
 Cpf - 
  ((norm(fAreas[facei])*norm(Cpf))/(norm(fAreas[facei])*norm(d)*cos(theta) + ROOTVSMALL))*d;
```

which becomes (disregarding `ROOTVSMALL`)

```
sv = Cpf - (norm(Cpf)/(norm(d)*cos(theta) + ROOTVSMALL))*d;
```

with `theta` being the angle between `d` and `fAreas[facei]`. Let's reorganize (again I am disregarding `ROOTVSMALL`)

```
sv = Cpf - norm(Cpf)/norm(d)*d*(1/(cos(theta) + ROOTVSMALL));
```

This way it is more clear that how this is a measure of skewness. `theta` can take values in the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ for meshes without degenerate elements and `1/cos(theta)` takes values in the interval $[1,\infty)$. At the last step, there is the normalization `svHat = sv/(mag(sv) + ROOTVSMALL);` which generates a unit vector `svHat` and gives you the skewness in each direction. 0 means no skewness in the given direction and other values will signify some skewness. I think $-1$ would be the most skewed case and correspond to a degenerate neighbouring element.

**Different measures of skewness**

As Maxim Umansky mentioned in the comments to the question, there is a wikipedia article which discusses [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_mesh#Skewness). Those are valid measures of skewness *of an element*, however, they do not say anything about the skewness of the grid. Except for the one based on equilateral volume. For example, according to those measures meshing of a rhombus domain with rhombus elements would be considered skewed, however, that is not what you want.

Another skewness definition I am familiar with is $$1-\frac{||c-d||}{|F|},$$ where $F$ is the face between two neighboring elements, $|F|$ is the area of the face, $c$ is the centroid of the face $F$ and $d$ is the midpoint of the line segment connecting the center of Own element to the center of neighbouring element. In this case, if $c$ and $d$ overlap for each couple of neighboring elements, it means the mesh is not skewed and you get a value of $1$. Hence, this definition of skewness is bounded above by $1$ but it can be an indefinitely large negative number.

Differences between this definition and OpenFOAM measure

- The one I am familiar with gives you a scalar, OpenFOAM measure returns a vector and tells you the direction of skewness too
- OpenFOAM measure is in $[-1,0]$ (if I am not wrong) and the other one is in $(-\infty,1]$.
- This one generalizes to polygons and polyhedra (this is a second hand information, i.e. something I heard some time ago), I am not sure about the OpenFOAM one.

Due to these reasons, even though I believe that they are equivalent definitions I cannot prove that they are, e.g. how do I compare a vector to a scalar? However, both would characterize the following two elements as highly skewed so that is my evidence towards their equivalence.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Abdullah, great code explaination. You mentioned different definitions of skewness, can you expand the answer and list some?

Comment: @Algo, thanks a lot for the compliments. I expanded my answer to include a small discussion on skewness definitions.

Comment: Can't upvote enough, many thanks.

Comment: One more thing, I would like to implement your metric in my code, is there any reference or paper for this formula?

Comment: @Algo, I don't know any references. I have it in my lecture notes from years ago but I do not have a cited paper there. When googled, I found that Ansys implements it as $$||c-d||/|F|$, so maybe you can refer to that. Probably, it is just considered common knowledge and noone knows the original paper.

Comment: Looking for a reference, I found this "Dose, B. (2013). CFD Simulations of a 2.5 MW wind turbine using ANSYS CFX and OpenFOAM (Doctoral dissertation, MSc Thesis, UAS Kiel and FhG IWES, Germany)." which has a different metric for skewness. They attribute their definition to OpenFOAM but it is definitely not what OpenFOAM implements according to the code above.